# How to connect specific AWS API Gateway stage to specific AWS lambda alias

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have AWS Lambda function and I invoke it calling AWS API Gateway via REST API. For Lambda function I configured two aliases with versioning - QA and Prod.

API Gateway is configured with Lambda Proxy Integration Request. I know about AWS API Gateway stages feature and I create two stages (QA and Prod respectively), but I don't see any settings for Lambda aliases in stage configuration.

How can I specify QA Lambda alias for QA stage and Prod Lambda alias for Prod API stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the integration request in API Gateway you can add the alias name to the end of the ARN to make sure your endpoint points to the correct alias. Something like this
`arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name:alias-name`

You can't tell an API Gateway stage to always use a specific Lambda alias and have multiple Gateway stages that all point towards different aliases.

Every time you need to deploy to a Gateway stage, you'll have to make sure your undeployed API Gateway endpoints are configured to point to the correct Lambda alias before deploying to the stage that matches that environment.

This get tricky to maintain, so I would recommend treating your two different stages as completely different resources using the serverless framework or another framework.

Useful resources:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-lambda
- https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/

Answer (score 1):

On your integration request, you will see the Lambda Function - click on it to edit and add :QA or :Prod after it and hit the checkmark, I think that will do it.

example: myLambda:Prod

Comment: but that would make stage specific?